# How can I export items from HTML into a .TXT file?

Tags: html, txt

I am trying to create a HTML program that can put the selected item from the dropdown created from the `<select>` and `<option>` scripts into a .txt file. The file is on Replit, so assume the text file already exists. This is my code, so far:

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="cardspicked.txt" method="get">
      <h3>What is your favorite low elixir Clash Royale card?</h3>
      <label for="low_elixir">Choose a card:</label>
      <select name = "low_elixir" id = "low_elixir">
        <option>Heal Spirit</option>
        <option>Skeletons</option>
        <option>Electro Spirit</option>
        <option>Fire Spirit</option>
        <option>Ice Spirit</option>
        <option>Wall Breakers</option>
        <option>Bats</option>
        <option>Spear Goblins</option>
        <option>Bomber</option>
        <option>Ice Golem</option>
        <option>Goblins</option>
        <option>Rage</option>
        <option>Giant Snowball</option>
        <option>Barbarian Barrel</option>
        <option>Zap</option>
        <option>The Log</option>
      </select>
      <hr>
      <h3>What about medium elixir?</h3>
      <label for="med_elixir">Choose a card:</label>
      <select name = "med_elixir" id = "med_elixir">
        <option>Knight</option>
        <option>Ice Wizard</option>
        <option>Mega Minion</option>
        <option>Dart Goblin</option>
        <option>Goblin Gang</option>
        <option>Miner</option>
        <option>Minions</option>
        <option>Bandit</option>
        <option>Princess</option>
        <option>Guards</option>
        <option>Archers</option>
        <option>Firecracker</option>
        <option>Royal Ghost</option>
        <option>Elixir Golem</option>
        <option>Skeleton Barrel</option>
        <option>Fisherman</option>
        <option>Skeleton Army</option>
        <option>Battle Healer</option>
        <option>Zappies</option>
        <option>Skeleton King</option>
        <option>Hunter</option>
        <option>Valkyrie</option>
        <option>Flying Machine</option>
        <option>Mighty Miner</option>
        <option>Electro Wizard</option>
        <option>Magic Archer</option>
        <option>Night Witch</option>
        <option>Inferno Dragon</option>
        <option>Battle Ram</option>
        <option>Mini P.E.K.K.A</option>
        <option>Musketeer</option>
        <option>Baby Dragon</option>
        <option>Golden Knight</option>
        <option>Skeleton Dragons</option>
        <option>Dark Prince</option>
        <option>Night Witch</option>
        <option>Lumberjack</option>
        <option>Cannon</option>
        <option>Tombstone</option>
        <option>Mortar</option>
        <option>Bomb Tower</option>
        <option>Tesla</option>
        <option>Furnace</option>
        <option>Goblin Cage</option>
        <option>Goblin Drill</option>
        <option>Goblin Barrel</option>
        <option>Royal Delivery</option>
        <option>Tornado</option>                     
        <option>Earthquake</option>
        <option>Arrows</option>
        <option>Clone</option>
        <option>Fireball</option>
        <option>Freeze</option>
        <option>Poison</option>
      </select>
      <hr>
      <h3>High elixir?</h3>
      <label for="high_elixir">Choose a card:</label>
      <select name = "high_elixir" id = "high_elixir">
        <option>Barbarians</option>
        <option>Royal Hogs</option>
        <option>Giant</option>
        <option>Prince</option>
        <option>Wizard</option>
        <option>Ram Rider</option>
        <option>Cannon Cart</option>
        <option>Rascals</option>
        <option>Witch</option>
        <option>Minion Horde</option>
        <option>Executioner</option>
        <option>Balloon</option>
        <option>Archer Queen</option>
        <option>Bowler</option>
        <option>Electro Dragon</option>
        <option>Elite Barbarians</option>
        <option>Goblin Giant</option>
        <option>Sparky</option>
        <option>Royal Giant</option>
        <option>Giant Skeleton</option>
        <option>Mega Knight</option>
        <option>P.E.K.K.A</option>
        <option>Royal Recruits</option>
        <option>Lava Hound</option>
        <option>Electro Giant</option>
        <option>Golem</option>
        <option>Three Musketeers</option>
        <option>Goblin Hut</option>
        <option>Inferno Tower</option>
        <option>Elixir Collector</option>
        <option>X-Bow</option>
        <option>Barbarian Hut</option>
        <option>Graveyard</option>
        <option>Lightning</option>
        <option>Rocket</option>
      </select>
      <hr>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" />Submit</button>

     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

I have checked many websites, including this one, to find an answer to this question, but none have been able to help me. Try to help, if possible.

Comment: html is not programming language, you cannot create html program and cannot implement such feature with pure html

Answer (score 0):

1. HTML is not a programming language; it is a markup language. You cannot use algorithms or anything else you would use in a traditional programming language in HTML.
2. JavaScript is client-side only. It is impossible to store anything on the server side from the client side using pure JavaScript; you need PHP for this. The only exception is if you have a backend running Node.js.

Check out [this article](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/serverless/glossary/client-side-vs-server-side/) for more info on server- vs. client-side programming.

In order to add such functionality using PHP, you would need to send a PHP POST request to the file on the server you want to add to. To learn more about PHP and form control using PHP, I suggest [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that it is impossible to do that without a PHP?

Comment: One doesn't need to use PHP; any backend will suffice.

Comment: "JavaScript is client-side only" — Umm. Here's a list of [about 20 different ways to run JavaScript server-side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_server-side_JavaScript_implementations). It was 2022 when you wrote this, Node.js is **super**-common.

Comment: @Quentin I meant "pure" JavaScript that runs in a web browser engine on the client side. Obviously, JS can and is used for server-side programming just as well as any other language that has such server frameworks as JavaScript does through Nodejs. As I said, "The only exception is if you have a backend running Node.js."

Comment: @BaconBoy672: PHP was just an example. As Michael M. said, writing any backend using any language (including JS) would suffice.

Comment: @humanbean — 19 other exceptions on that link. And JS in the browser isn't "pure", it's just "in the browser" (with DOM and Web APIs bolted on to make it impure).

Answer (score -1):

You can not do this on HTML alone as HTML is not a programming language.
You will need to use some JS which can be achieved like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
var data = document.getElementById("low_elixir").options[].text;

fs.writeFile('data.txt', data, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
})
```

```html
<select name="low_elixir" id="low_elixir">
  <option>Heal Spirit</option>
  <option>Skeletons</option>
  <option>Electro Spirit</option>
  <option>Fire Spirit</option>
  <option>Ice Spirit</option>
  <option>Wall Breakers</option>
  <option>Bats</option>
  <option>Spear Goblins</option>
  <option>Bomber</option>
  <option>Ice Golem</option>
  <option>Goblins</option>
  <option>Rage</option>
  <option>Giant Snowball</option>
  <option>Barbarian Barrel</option>
  <option>Zap</option>
  <option>The Log</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your code won't run on the browser. The `require()` API and the `fs` module are both node.js only.